# Photo Library and Camera are accessible after permission got denied

Tags: ios, authorization, media

I'm currently working on an app where I need to access either the photo library or the camera (or even both, it's up to the user).

If I close the app and deny the access to both camera and library for the app.

After restarting my App, it's still possible to access both, I can open and use the camera or even pick a photo from the library. 
How is this possible, I thought Apple would restrict the access.

Comment: I also thought they would restrict the access but you should also check the permissions and prompt where/when needed

Comment: How are you checking their permission selection programatically?

Comment: @KSigWyatt usually you get the alert with context from your info.plist file. I was just wondering that the access is denied but apple still lets the app use the camera for example

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. Apple always restrict use of camera or photo library if access is denied. Please use following code to check current status and verify it.

```
    import Photos

    if type == .CAMERA{

        if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
            completionHander(true) //Allowed
        } else {
            //Dont Know
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) -> Void in
                completionHander(granted)
            })
        }
    }else{
        let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            completionHander(true)//Allowed
            break
        case .denied, .restricted :
            completionHander(false)//Not Allowed
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            //Dont Know
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
                switch status {
                case .authorized:
                    completionHander(true)
                    break
                case .denied, .restricted:
                    completionHander(false)
                    break
                case .notDetermined:
                    completionHander(false)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing now but, I thought it would be restricted by Apple.

Comment: can you share me screenshot of setting of your app?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I know the answer... 
I just didn't get the concept. 
If I deny the access to the photoLibrary it is not possible to save images but, if Camera access is granted I can still use the photoLibrary. 
If camera access is denied, I still get the alert with the context from the info.plist